# How to create ssl certificate chain?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have public key certificate and private key and I have uploaded both keys in AWS cloudfront service.

I have tried to configure cloudfront and select custom SSL certificate and clicked on "YES EDIT" button. I received the below error message:

"com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist in the IAM certificate store, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: c169e804-ef21-11e4-a864-99c1866d5c97)"

Please give advice on above error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "create" it.  The certificate chain is made up of one or more additional "intermediate" certificates provided by the certificate authority that generated your certificate.